# django auth ldap

Tags: django, authentication, active-directory, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I've been trying to get the LDAP -> Django groups mappings working without success.  Everything seems to work fine except for the group mapping part.  My LDAP backend is Active Directory.  I'm using django-auth-ldap 1.0.10.

**settings.py:**

```
import ldap, logging
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, ActiveDirectoryGroupType

logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://sub.domain.com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'CN=Bind Account,OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'passwd'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)",)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=Groups,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)")

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType()
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
#AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: False,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: False,
} 

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_staff":  "CN=SomeGroup,OU=Groups,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com",
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

**and my logs**

```
search_s('OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com', 2, '(uid=myuser)') returned 1 objects: CN=My User,OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com
Populating Django user myuser
CN=My User,OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com is a member of CN=SomeGroup,OU=Groups,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com
search_s('OU=Groups,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com', 2, '(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=CN=My User,OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=Chicago,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com))') returned 0 objects: 
Populating Django user profile for myuser
```

Comment: This is an old question, but here's a link for those who might be searching for a solution to a related problem occurring with certain AD installations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721603/django-auth-ldap-direct-bind-using-samaccountname/29019057

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer.  In the group search, i changed the filter to be objectClass=group instead of objectClass=groupOfNames.  All is well.

Comment: Thanks for posting... this got me authenticating against our AD infrastructure.