# Django Auth LDAP - Direct Bind using sAMAccountName

Tags: python, django, active-directory, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

There are two ways to authenticate a user using Django Auth LDAP

1. Search/Bind and
2. Direct Bind.

The first one involves connecting to the LDAP server either anonymously or with a fixed account and searching for the distinguished name of the authenticating user. Then we can attempt to bind again with the user’s password.

The second method is to derive the user’s DN from his username and attempt to bind as the user directly.

I want to be able to do a direct bind using the userid (sAMAccountName) and password of the user who is trying to gain access to the application. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this? At the moment, I cannot seem to make this work due to the problem explained below.

In my case, the DN of users in LDAP is of the following format

```
**'CN=Steven Jones,OU=Users,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp'**
```

This basically translates to 'CN=FirstName LastName,OU=Users,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp'

This is preventing me from using Direct Bind as the **sAMAccountName** of the user is **sjones** and this is the parameter that corresponds to the user name (%user) and I can't figure out a way to frame a proper **AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE** to derive the User's DN using.

Due to the above explained problem, I am using Search/Bind for now but this requires me to have a fixed user credential to be specified in **AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN** and **AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD**.

Here is my current **settings.py** configuration

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://10.5.120.161:389"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN='CN=Steven Jones,OU=Users,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD='fga.1234'
#AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = 'CN=%(user)s,OU=Appl Groups,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(
    LDAPSearch("OU=Users, OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),
    LDAPSearch("OU=Users,OU=Regional,OU=Locales,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"),
    )
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {"first_name": "givenName", "last_name": "sn","email":"mail"}
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("CN=GG_BusinessApp_US,OU=Appl Groups,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = 'CN=GG_BusinessApp_US,OU=Appl Groups,OU=Central,OU=US,DC=client,DC=corp'
```

Looking forward for some guidance from the wonderful folks in here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I ran across ticket 21 in the now-deleted bitbucket repository. (`cant-bind-and-search-on-activedirectory`). The issues were not migrated to [their github](https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap/issues), but the author brought up a way to change the library files for `django-auth-ldap` so that it could do a direct bind.

It came down to changing `<python library path>/django_auth_ldap/backend.py` to include two lines in `_authenticate_user_dn`:

```
if sticky and ldap_settings.AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH:
    self._search_for_user_dn()
```

I was able to get this to work on my local machine that was running Arch Linux 3.9.8-1-ARCH, but I was unable to replicate it on the dev server running Ubuntu 13.04.

Hopefully this can help.

Comment: Thanks @amethystdragon Looks like this will solve my problem. I will give it a try shortly.

Comment: it works if u have deprecated version of django_auth_ldap, like <= 2.2.0. our production for some reason had very old legacy django project that used ldap for auth, such pain in the ass.. 

so u can either update or use this fix

Answer (score 5):

(This is actually a comment to @amethystdragon's answer, but it's a bunch of code, so posting as a separate answer.) The problem still seems to exist with django_auth_ldap 1.2.5. Here's an updated patch. If you don't want or can't modify the source code, monkey-patching is possible. Just put this code to eg. end of `settings.py`. (And yes, I know monkey-patching is ugly.)

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap import backend

def monkey(self, password):
  """
  Binds to the LDAP server with the user's DN and password. Raises
  AuthenticationFailed on failure.
  """
  if self.dn is None:
    raise self.AuthenticationFailed("failed to map the username to a DN.")

  try:
    sticky = self.settings.BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER

    self._bind_as(self.dn, password, sticky=sticky)

    #### The fix -->
    if sticky and self.settings.USER_SEARCH:
      self._search_for_user_dn()
    #### <-- The fix

  except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
    raise self.AuthenticationFailed("user DN/password rejected by LDAP server.")

backend._LDAPUser._authenticate_user_dn = monkey
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, but I didn't want to modify the `settings.py` file. The fix for me was to comment out the line "AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,ou=path,dc=to,dc=domain"". I also added `NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType` as part of my troubleshooting. Not sure if it's necessary, but it's working now so I'm leaving it. Here's my `ldap_config.py` file.

```
import ldap

# Server URI
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://urlForLdap"

# The following may be needed if you are binding to Active Directory.
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
       # ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 1,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
}

# Set the DN and password for the NetBox service account.
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=Netbox,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"

# Include this setting if you want to ignore certificate errors. This might be needed to accept a self-signed cert.
# Note that this is a NetBox-specific setting which sets:
#     ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
LDAP_IGNORE_CERT_ERRORS = True

from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType

# This search matches users with the sAMAccountName equal to the provided username. This is required if the user's
# username is not in their DN (Active Directory).
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx",
                                    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                    "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")

# If a user's DN is producible from their username, we don't need to search.
# AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,ou=users,dc=corp,dc=loc"

# You can map user attributes to Django attributes as so.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType, NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType

# This search ought to return all groups to which the user belongs. django_auth_ldap uses this to determine group
# heirarchy.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("dc=xxx,dc=xxx", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                    "(objectClass=group)")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType()

# Define a group required to login.
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "CN=NetBox_Users,OU=NetBox,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"

# Define special user types using groups. Exercise great caution when assigning superuser status.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "CN=NetBox_Active,OU=NetBox,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx",
    "is_staff": "CN=NetBox_Staff,OU=NetBox,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx",
    "is_superuser": "CN=NetBox_Superuser,OU=NetBox,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"
}

# For more granular permissions, we can map LDAP groups to Django groups.
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

# Cache groups for one hour to reduce LDAP traffic
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem where the old ldap server had a dn that started with uid, but the DN of the new one starts with CN ('Steven Jones'). I used this configuration (which solved it for me) in setting.py:

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'CN=adreader,CN=Users,DC=xxx, DC=yyy'

from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch
import ldap
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(base_dn='ou=People, ou=xxx, dc=yyy, dc=zzz, 
  scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr='(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using direct bind (as shown below) and then **passing the common name in the login interface** would do the job, and thus it is not needed to set static authentication credentials.

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "CN=%(user)s,OU=users,OU=OR-TN,DC=OrangeTunisie,DC=intra"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers did not work for me, but I have found a way to make it work.
The trick is to use sAMAAcountname in combination with the domain name to bind.

1. modify the template DN in order for it to use username@domain.com format.
2. use modified monkey patch to lookup and store the real user CN (self._user_dn).

Settings:

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = '%(user)s@example.com'
```

Patch:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap import backend

def monkey(self, password):
    """
    Binds to the LDAP server with the user's DN and password. Raises
    AuthenticationFailed on failure.
    """
    if self.dn is None:
        raise self.AuthenticationFailed("failed to map the username to a DN.")

    try:
        sticky = self.settings.BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER

    self._bind_as(self.dn, password, sticky=sticky)

    # Search for the user DN -->
    if sticky and self.settings.USER_SEARCH:
        self._user_dn = self._search_for_user_dn()

    except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        raise self.AuthenticationFailed("user DN/password rejected by LDAP server.")

backend._LDAPUser._authenticate_user_dn = monkey
```